# Address of global symbol table (GOT) in PIC/PIE binaries

Tags: c, assembly, x86, inline-assembly, fpic

I am maintaining the [JIT compiler for the virtual machine in ioquake3](https://github.com/thiloschulz/ioq3/blob/master/code/qcommon/vm_x86.c).

Recently someone tried to build a PIE binary from ioquake3, however compiled code makes extensive use of the EBX register which in PIC code and thus PIE binaries seems to be a fixed register containing the GOT address.

The virtual machine may call into GCC-compiled code at a fixed point so there I will need to restore EBX to the GOT address.
For that the JIT-compiler code needs to know the GOT address so that it can emit code that restores EBX to that address.
I imagine you could directly use inline assembly like so:

```
void *gotptr;

__asm__ volatile("\n": "=b" (gotptr));
```

Compiled code is directly called from the JIT-compiler code so EBX should be the same at JIT compile and at the call into the VM. My question is: would this work, and is there a different way to retrieve the GOT address from C code, for instance, is there a symbol defined that specifies that address, or is there a function that returns it?

Comment: You shouldn't need to restore EBX.  A PIC compiled function should have something at the start of the function that sets it. (eg. a call to `__x86.get_pc_thunk.bx`).

Comment: Holy cow you're right. I guess it makes sense, because each PIC object will come with its own symbol table. If you add your answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [System V i386 ABI](http://www.sco.com/developers/devspecs/abi386-4.pdf) its the responsibility of the function being called to set EBX if necessary, so there shouldn't be any need to restore it when calling PIC/PIE compiled functions. As the ABI states:

> Position-independent code uses the `%ebx` register to hold the address
>   of the global offset table. If a function needs the global offset
>   table’s address, either directly or indirectly, it is responsible for
>   computing the value.